# Updating a quantity based on another table within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is honestly pretty simple but I'm banging my head on the wall. Users can subscribe to an educational program but there are a finite number of subscriptions. What I'm looking to do is deduct from the total/return to the total based on create/destroy methods. So I have the following models:

```
User
has_many :requests
scope :managers, -> {where(azure_manager: true) }

Training
has_many :requests
validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
validates :subscriptions_available, numericality: { greater_than_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }
has_attached_file :avatar,
 styles: {
   large: ['304>x304>', :png],
   medium: ['225>x225>', :png],
   small: ['112>x112>', :png]
 }

Requests
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :training
has_many :approvals, dependent: :destroy
```

Since request controls the create/destroy I put it in the controller the following code:

```
after_create :remove_from_sub
after_destroy :return_to_sub

 def create
  @requests = Request.create(request_params)
  respond_with @requests
 end

def remove_from_sub
 training.subscriptions_available -= self.subscriptions_available
 training.save
end

def return_to_sub
  training.subscriptions_available += self.subscriptions_available
  training.save
 end
```

My issue are the two methods that will affect the Training table and the quantity. How do I correctly hit that attribute?

EDIT:
I realized I'm not even drawing the Training model in accurately so I switched it to:

```
def remove_from_sub
  @traininge = Training.find_by(params[:id])
  @training.subscriptions_available -= self.subscriptions_available
  @training.save
end

def return_to_sub
  @training = Training.find_by(params[:id])
  @training.subscriptions_available += self.subscriptions_available
  @training.save
end
```

Also updated the models with all the validations.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be a bit more specific on your problem (do you get an error, or just an unexpected result? If so, what is it?). Also, it would be great if you could post your training and request models

Comment: Have you thought about turning the logic around and using counter caches? You wouldn't have to maintain the counters yourself, and could check when creating a new request if `training.requests_count < subscriptions_available`.

Comment: The frustrating part is that I have to use some Oauth for Azure that's causing some issues with spinning up the server so I can't quickly test. And I'm too much of a n00b to know how to test in pry.

Comment: What is the problem  you're having?  Your thought process on using callbacks is correct way to do what you want.